# What do just two IPs in hosts file without any domain name be indicative of?

Tags: networking, ip, hosts-file

A friend of mine was complaining about very slow internet on his Windows 7 laptop. Out of curiosity I just had a look at the 'hosts' file on his laptop and some entries therein surprised me.

There were entries like loopback address followed by some real IP.
I know loopback address followed by a domain name can in a way block opening that website on your local system, but I am not too sure what would loopback address followed by a real IP be indicative of?

It looks something like

`127.0.0.1      a.b.c.d`  (where a.b.c.d is some real IP address)

Just note that I am restricting the scope of this question to the meaning of such entry in hosts. Why internet is slow on my friend’s laptop is in a way out of scope. It’s just mentioned as a context in which I stumbled upon those entries in hosts.

Comment: On a known-good device, do some research on the a.b.c.d address.  Whois lookup , lookup on malware alert sites.  
Is this laptop used by a developer?  Is it a shared laptop?

Comment: It's indicative of someone who doesn't understand name resolution but learned the hosts file can reroute (usually just blackhole) undesired domainnames and thinks this applies to addresses also. But as you more or less guessed it doesn't work, because addresses aren't names, although in some other contexts they can be equivalent.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I think your comment qualifies as a proper answer. I have seen some computers like this as well and it was in every case the user who followed blindly some YouTube guide without understanding what he was doing.